# how to stop getting mouse click events in flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, flash-builder

I have made a hierarchy in which there is a main page,  using add element i have attached a component mxml of type group. There is a single button on main page when clicked it should add children of type group in that group type mxml component along with two buttons. Now using one of buttons i am attaching another component mxml type group. the problem is even they overlap i can still excess the children groups of first group component mxml. how can i stop this mouse events to happen.

Comment: Its better to put some mxml code to explain your hierarchy. Anyway, as far as I got your query, you could use event.stopImmediatePropagation() after handling your event in eventhandler function.

Comment: like @M.D. said, some code would be very helpful

Comment: Post some code, dont know exactly what you want, By adding the mouseChildren = false and mouseEnabled = false, the mouse-events will not generate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think those kind of events usually bubble up to parent components.
You can try using the following code in your mouse click event listener to stop further propagation:

```
private function onMouseClicked(event: MouseEvent): void {
    event.stopPropagation();
    ... do whatever you wanted when smth was clicked ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By setting enabled, mouseChildren, mouseEnabled to false, you will disable the entire component and it's children. example below

```
private var myPreviousGroupComponent:Group = null;
function addNewGroup():void
{
    if(myPreviousGroupComponent != null)
    {
        myPreviousGroupComponent.enabled = false;
        myPreviousGroupComponent.mouseChildren = false;
        myPreviousGroupComponent.mouseEnabled = false;
    }

    var newGroup:Group = new Group();
    addElement(newGroup);

    myPreviousGroupComponent = newGroup;
}
```